# Get Android EditText to scroll horizontally without word wrap

Tags: java, android, horizontal-scrolling

So I have an android app that transcribes normal text to ascii-art text, say like from "hello world" to

```
  _          _ _                            _     _ 
 | |__   ___| | | ___   __      _____  _ __| | __| |
 | '_ \ / _ \ | |/ _ \  \ \ /\ / / _ \| '__| |/ _` |
 | | | |  __/ | | (_) |  \ V  V / (_) | |  | | (_| |
 |_| |_|\___|_|_|\___/    \_/\_/ \___/|_|  |_|\__,_|
```

(sorry mobile users, you might not be able to see that, idk)

and naturally, I need the EditText in which the final product (the ascii-art text) doesn't word-wrap since if it did, it'd look all jumbled and everything. I need a horizontally scrolling EditText. Here is my current code.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    String letter;
    EditText textView = new EditText(this);
    Typeface courier = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"Courier_Prime.ttf");
    textView.setTextSize(20);
    textView.setTypeface(courier);
    setContentView(textView);
    String value;
    String toPrint;
    int textLength = message.length();
    for(int i = 0; i <= 14; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < textLength; j++){
            letter = message.substring(j,j+1).toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault());
            value = letter + i;
            toPrint = isometric.get(value);
            textView.append(toPrint);
            if(j == textLength-1){
                textView.append("\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

And nothing but a little RelativeLayout in the xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.dumpong.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity" >

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/asciiBox"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm not exactly sure how to make a horizontal scroll for the EditText though. Programmatic or through XML is fine. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I've misunderstood but here is how to have an EditText which can scroll horizontally.

The needed layout :

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#333333"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/TEXT_STATUS_ID"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:textColor="#cccccc"
            android:textSize="35sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

And here is the associated code : you have to call init() under OnCreate().

```
private EditText mEditText;
private HorizontalScrollView mScrollView;

private void init() {
    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TEXT_STATUS_ID);
    mScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.SCROLLER_ID);
    // loadDoc();
    String s = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
            + "Aliquam tempus convallis metus, ac congue dui elementum ut."
            + "Suspendisse rutrum non sapien feugiat fermentum."
            + "Phasellus vulputate quam in sapien vulputate venenatis."
            + "Pellentesque porta tincidunt nisi, et scelerisque augue facilisis nec."
            + "Curabitur eget risus quam."
            + "Maecenas pellentesque egestas enim, in ornare nisl lobortis id."
            + "Nunc vitae facilisis libero, vitae porttitor tellus.";
    mEditText.setText(s);
    scrollToBottom();
}

private void scrollToBottom() {
    mScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mEditText.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
            mEditText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
            mScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, mEditText.getBottom());
        }
    });
}
```

Don't hesitate to comment if I've misunderstood or if you need more explanation.

Comment: I'm not sure I *quite* understand how to use this yet. It keeps giving me errors on the `public void scrollToBottom() {` section about mScrollView and mEditText not existing, maybe a scope issue?

Comment: I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I'll ask another question and upvote since this has been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping your edit text with a horizontalscrollview should do it.

```
<HorizontalScrollView> 
  <Edittext>...</Edittext>
 </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: I tried that. It didn't work, for some reason. I'll try again.

Comment: Try setting the horizontal scroll view with to fillparent

Comment: you mean fillparent or `match_parent`? I've never heard of fillparent before and match_parent didn't work. Again, I'll see what I can do haha

Comment: I mean't fill_parent.

Answer (score 0):

- **Horizontal Scrolling EditText**

Adapted from Kassisdion's answer [tested and working on api 21; android: 5.0]:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top">

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical|horizontal"/>

</HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```